# Using update-in without a get-in to retrieve the value to modify

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure and I'm trying to update a map using the update-in and anonymous functions

```
(def items {:my-item {:item-count 10}})

(update-in items [:my-item :item-count]
           (fn [%] (- (get-in items [:my-item :item-count])  3)))
```

The expected results are that the item count should be now 7, my code works but I'm wondering if I can do this without calling the get-in method.

Another approach I tried is below:

```
(update-in items [:my-item :item-count]
           (dec (fn [%] 3)))
```

Which gives me

```
cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

Comment: Just a side-note, an anonymous function that subtracts 3 from any argument it's given can be defined using macro: `#(- % 3)`. Hope you'll figure out the rest, REPL is your friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your anonymous function should take the thing it wants to modify and use that instead of doing the get-in

```
(update-in items [:my-item :item-count]
       (fn [item-count] (- item-count 3)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(update-in items [:my-item :item-count] - 3)
```

Comment: How can it be done still with the anonymous function?

Comment: @VutiviCanCode Keep in mind that `-` is a function just as much as your anonymous one is. Thus, you can substitute your own function in place of `-`, and it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
(def items {:my-item {:item-count 10}})
(update-in items [:my-item :item-count] #(- % 3))
```